# Не записывается элемент словаря в переменную

Tags: массивы, golang

Привет. У меня возникла такая проблема. Есть строка-json, которая преобразуется в map. Внутри этой строки есть массив. Проблема заключается в следующем. Функция `Unmarshall` преобразует строку в json, после чего я пытаюсь достать указанный выше массив, но получаю на это ошибку:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[int]int
```

Привожу пример json`а:

```
map[lon:52.328066 fias_id:89bc3c83-6060-4737-a497-0d4e64cdff16 polygon_osm_id:0 path:Россия, Кировская область, Верхнекамский район, Пещера, Нижняя улица place_type: is_capital:0 official_status_ru: alt_names:[] info:{} id:376672 msg: type:street lat:59.192944 name:Нижняя улица parent_id:376618 parent_ids:[0 1 72 371251 376618]]
```

Я хочу получить `parent_ids`. Делаю я это так:

```
parent := dataJson["parent_ids"].(map[int]int) // Здесь падает программа
```

Кусок кода, который осуществляет преобразования:

```
json.Unmarshal(bytes, &dataJson)
fmt.Println(dataJson)
parent := dataJson["parent_ids"].(map[int]int)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вам же пишется, что `parent_ids` - это слайс, а не мап. И кстати, ваши данные нормально ложатся на структуру, так зачем вы делаете через `map`?

Comment: Я об этом не подумал. Наверное, так и сделаю. Могли бы Вы подсказать, как решить мне мой вопрос. Хотелось бы с ним разобарться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если схема данных более-менее статична, то лучше декодируйте в структуры:

```
type data struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
    Lon float64 `json:"lon"`
    // ...
    ParentIDs []int `json:"parent_ids"`
}

// ...

d := &data{}
err := json.Unmarshal(body, d)
fmt.Printf("err: %v parent IDs: %v", err, d.ParentIDs)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SpT1eb7Yys.

---

**EDIT:** если же у вас схема не статическая, придётся делать через множество ассертов по типам:

```
parentIDsArr := dataJSON["parent_ids"].([]interface{})
parentIDs := []float64{}
for _, id := range parentIDsArr {
    parentIDs = append(parentIDs, id.(float64))
}
fmt.Println(parentIDs)
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, структура не статична. Поэтому хотелось бы работать с интерфейсами

Comment: @hedgehogues Смотрите правку.

Comment: `cannot use parent (type []interface {}) as type map[int]int in field value`

Comment: тип: `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(dataJson["parent_ids"]) )` вот такой: `[]interface {}`

Comment: Откуда вы вообще берёте `map[int]int`? Я вам ещё раз говорю, там массив.

Comment: Я понимаю, что там массив. Но компилятор мне выдаёт, что там map[int]int.

Comment: Нет, компилятор вам говорит, что там `[]interface {}`, который *вы* пытаетесь где-то использовать как `map[int]int`.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Спасибо Вам за помощь. Компилятор всё это время говорил про другую строку. На этой же строке всё было прекрасно.